# Visual Studio 2010 losing references in Visual Web Part project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference

I am having a problem with Visual Studio 2010 losing references.  I've seen this several times now and it may not be relevant that it's a Visual Web Part, but that's usually what I'm working with so I thought I should point that out.

The scenario is this: I create a new VWP project, then add two new class library projects (business logic and data access layers) and then add references to each other.  It usually works fine for a while, but at some point in debugging it will suddenly fail building with the "are you missing a reference?" message even though it still shows the references.  The work-around I have is to to re-add the reference (even though it's already in the references list) and will work again for a while until another (seemingly) random debug session will fail the build again.

Both of the class libraries and the VWP target the .NET 3.5 Framework and the x64 platform.  VS is fully patched.